# Running multiline test cases

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I have the following prompt:

- We want you to calculate the sum of squares of given integers, excluding any negatives.
- The first line of the input will be an integer `N` (`1 <= N <= 100`), indicating the number of test cases to follow.
- Each of the test cases will consist of a line with an integer `X` (`0 < X <= 100`), followed by another line consisting of `X` number of space-separated integers `Yn` (`-100 <= Yn <= 100`).
- For each test case, calculate the sum of squares of the integers, excluding any negatives, and print the calculated sum in the output.
- **Note:** There should be no output until all the input has been received.
- **Note 2:** Do not put blank lines between test cases solutions.
- **Note 3:** Take input from standard input, and output to standard output.

**Specific Rules for Python Solution:**

- Your source code must be a single file, containing at least a main function
- Do not use any `for` loop, `while` loop, or any list / set / dictionary comprehension

[image: Sample Input and Output]

I have written my `square_sum` function as:

```
def square_sum(arr):
    if not arr:
        return 0
    
    value = arr[0]
    if value < 0:
        value = 0
        
    return value**2 + square_sum(arr[1:])
        
square_sum([9, 6, -53, 32, 16])
```

However, I cannot figure out how to run the multiline test cases on my function and display the result in the aforementioned format. Interestingly, there can be any number of test cases so how do I add the capability to accommodate them? I would like some guidance in this part, thank you.

Comment: @MadPhysicist It's the prompt I was given. As much as I would like the flexibility to use loops myself, I can't in this case.

Comment: Are you asking how to read lines of input from stdin?

Comment: I'm asking how to read the lines from input in such a manner that all the test cases pass through my `square_sum` function successfully. Something like `x, y = map(int, input().split())` ought to be used as far as my imagination goes

Comment: What if you just pass the result of `split` to your existing function and apply `int` there, avoiding the `map`?

Comment: Also, you will want an outer recursive function to read the multiple test cases.

Comment: Does `map` and `sum` fall under not using a loop, in the sense that the question wants you to to use recursion only?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Can you show me how to code that outer recursive function to read the multiple test cases?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I believe map and sum can still be used

Comment: I posted an answer that does not require using either.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this assignment is to see how to replace all iteration with recursion, and withholding all judgement on the wisdom of doing so, here is a sample solution.

You have already implemented the inner loop. My suggestion would be to add the parsing to that loop, since otherwise you have to either use `map` or replace it with another recursion.

```
def square_sum(lst):
    if not lst:
        return 0
    value = int(lst[0])
    if value < 0:
        value = 0
    return value**2 + square_sum(lst[1:])
```

The outer loop will need to read two lines: the first (discarded) line will contain the number of elements. The second line will contain the strings that you will pass to `square_sum`. To control the depth of your recursion, use the first line of the input, which tells you how many samples there will be:

```
def run(n):
    count = int(input())
    print(square_sum(input().split()))
    if n > 1:
        run(n - 1)

def main()
    n = int(input())
    run(n)
```

Your question asks for a `main` function. If you need to run it in your module, go ahead and do that:

```
main()
```

Comment: `Sample Input 2 4 3 -1 1 14 5 9 6 -53 32 16 Sample Output 206 1397`

Comment: In above sample input 2 is the number of test-cases for which the program has to take the number of elements. 4 is the number of elements and then 4 elements are taken as input and for the second test case, 5 is the number of elements. For output first, the sum of the first test case is printed and then sum for the second one is printed

Comment: My point is once the input statement executes, the entire input is going to be provided in one single line as above ^

Comment: Also, you've made another mistake. We need to exclude the negatives, not square them too

Comment: @Hamza. I fixed the negative issue. Hadn't read that instruction carefully.

Comment: I don't know what you mean about a single line. The sample input is clearly stated and shown to be provided on multiple lines. `input` reads one line at a time.